# Java getProperties

Tags: java, cpu, x86-64, getproperties

The command:

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

returns the following:

```
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
```

I can't understand why it's amd64. I have Lenovo with Intel 3i,  Win7 (where the code was tested) and Ubuntu. Where is the trick?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

All Intel x64 systems use the Amd64 instruction set under license.  In terms of instruction set, its an Amd64.

Answer (score 1):

AMD was has introduced 64bit CPU instruction first. It is still called AMD64 but meant are both Intel 64 bits and AMD 64 bits x86 processors. A better name would be x86_64...

Answer (score 1):

The AMD64 is an architecture, like x86 was.

[Read more](http://www.coralcdn.org/05au-cs240c/lab/amd64/AMD64-3.pdf)